# Database Design: Constrain one table against another tables Foreign Key

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have the following tables in a SQL database, I want to ensure that a Contact can't be created against a ContactType and Matter that have different Clients.  I'm not sure how I can go about creating that constraint though or even what it might be called to look it up.

```sql
CREATE TABLE _Clients (
    [Id]   int IDENTITY NOT NULL, 
    [Name] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT [PK__Clients] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id ASC))

CREATE TABLE _Matters (
    [Id] int IDENTITY NOT NULL, 
    [ClientId] int NOT NULL, 
    [Name] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT [PK__Matters] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id ASC))

CREATE TABLE _ContactTypes (
    [Id] int IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    [ClientId] int NOT NULL,
    [Name] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT [PK__ContactTypes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id ASC))

CREATE TABLE _Contacts (
    [Id] int IDENTITY NOT NULL, 
    [MatterId] int NOT NULL, 
    [ContactTypeId] int NOT NULL,
    [Name] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT [PK__Contacts] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id ASC))

ALTER TABLE _Matters ADD CONSTRAINT [FK__Matters_Clients] FOREIGN KEY([ClientId])
REFERENCES _Clients ([Id])

ALTER TABLE _ContactTypes ADD CONSTRAINT [FK__ContactTypes_Clients] FOREIGN KEY([ClientId])
REFERENCES _Clients ([Id])

ALTER TABLE _Contacts ADD CONSTRAINT [FK__Contacts_ContactTypes] FOREIGN KEY ([ContactTypeId])
REFERENCES _ContactTypes ([Id])

ALTER TABLE _Contacts ADD CONSTRAINT [FK__Contacts_Matters] FOREIGN KEY([MatterId])
REFERENCES _Matters ([Id])

INSERT INTO _Clients VALUES ('Client 1'), ('Client 2')
INSERT INTO _Matters VALUES (1, 'Matter 1.1'), (2, 'Matter 2.1')
INSERT INTO _ContactTypes VALUES (1, 'Client 1 Contact Type'), (2, 'Client 2 Contact Type')
INSERT INTO _Contacts VALUES (1, 2, 'Invalid Contact')

SELECT cl1.[Name] AS MatterClient, cl2.[Name] AS ContactTypeClient, m.[Name] AS Matter, ct.[Name] AS ContactType, c.[Name] AS Contact
FROM _Contacts c 
JOIN _Matters m ON c.MatterId = m.Id
JOIN _Clients cl1 ON m.ClientId = cl1.Id
JOIN _ContactTypes ct ON c.ContactTypeId = ct.Id
JOIN _Clients cl2 ON ct.ClientId = cl2.Id
```

| MatterClient | ContactTypeClient | Matter | Contact Type | Contact |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Client 1 | Client 2 | Matter 1.1 | Client 2 Contact Type | Invalid Contact |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `ClientId` to the `Contact` table, then create the foreign keys over that.

You also need to add secondary unique constraints over the other tables in order to have such a foreign key.

```
ALTER TABLE _Matters
    ADD CONSTRAINT Uq_Matters_ClientId UNIQUE (Id, ClientId);

ALTER TABLE _ContactTypes
    ADD CONSTRAINT Uq_ContactTypes_ClientId UNIQUE (Id, ClientId);

CREATE TABLE _Contacts (
    Id int IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    ClientId int NOT NULL,
    MatterId int NOT NULL, 
    ContactTypeId int NOT NULL,
    Name nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id ASC),
    FOREIGN KEY (ContactTypeId, ClientId) REFERENCES _ContactTypes (Id, ClientId),
    FOREIGN KEY(MatterId, ClientId) REFERENCES _Matters (Id, ClientId)
  )
```

Now each `Contact` must be against a single `ClientId`, and the foreign keys refer to the same `ClientId`.

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/XbppJ8uK)

---

If for whatever reason you do not wish to modify the tables, you can instead enforce a multi-table constraint using a little-known hack with indexed views.

First create a table with at least two rows in it.

```
CREATE TABLE DummyTwoRows (dummy int);
INSERT DummyTwoRows VALUES (NULL),(NULL);
```

Then create a view that selects invalid rows, and cross joins that table.

```
CREATE VIEW vwSameClientId
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT
  tr.dummy,
  m.ClientId AS MatterClientId,
  ct.ClientId AS ContactTypeClient
FROM dbo._Contacts c
JOIN dbo._Matters m ON m.Id = c.MatterId
JOIN dbo._ContactTypes ct ON ct.Id = c.ContactTypeId
CROSS JOIN dbo.DummyTwoRows tr
WHERE m.ClientId <> ct.ClientId;
```

Then index it

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX ClientIdMustBeSame ON vwSameClientId (dummy, MatterClientId, ContactTypeClient);
```

Any invalid rows will fail that unique index. Note that the indexed view always contains zero rows and doesn't take up any space. Also, `MatterClientId` and `ContactTypeClient` are unnecessary, but can be useful to show the in the eror message.

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/j8rzO-FV)

Comment: Thanks, after a lot of banging my head against a wall I think I found a similar question somewhere with the same answer as the first part.  That's what I'm going with rather than hacky ways.  Interestingly I asked Chat GPT as well and it suggested creating a UDF and putting a Check Constraint on, it works but I'm not sure of performance.

Comment: Yeah scalar UDF in a check constraint is a known performance issue. It prevents parallelism among other things, even when not selecting that column, and it executes separately for every single row you insert or update.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to normalize the `MatterId` and `ContactTypeId` out of the `_Contacts` table, and the `ClientId` out of the `_ContactTypes` and `_Matters` tables, into a linking table that also includes `ContactId` like so:

```
CREATE TABLE ContactMatterContactTypeClients
(
    ContactId INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    MatterId INT NOT NULL,
    ContactTypeId INT NOT NULL,
    ClientId INT NOT NULL
)
```

You would then foreign key each field in the `ContactMatterContactTypeClients` table to their appropriate source tables.

Then implicitly by design, it's not possible for there to be a `ContactId` with a `MatterId` and `ContactTypeId` combination of different `ClientIds`.

---

Feel free to pick a better name for the linking table. I suck at naming things.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I went with the other solution because it required fewer changes to the current schema.